# Python coverting itertools.chain to map

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to pyspark and trying to understand the code below from some prod code.

```
test_map =  {"A":1,"B":2, "C":3, "D":4}
test_mapping = create_map([lit(ele) for ele in chain(*test_map.items())])
```

The code above gives me error.

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_jvm'

Not sure what is wrong with that. Can somebody explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the code above. In fact, it doesn't "run" anything, because Spark transformation is lazy.

This is the actual result of your code:

```py
print(test_mapping)
# Column<'map(A, 1, B, 2, C, 3, D, 4)'>
```

Comment: I have the same problem. My mapping used to work fine, and all of a sudden, it doesn't work any more. 
Your answer doesn't solve anything though. The code still gives an error.